# want to know whether grammar in this sentence is correct or not?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

From being vacillated on whether to go with this project or not, into creating a project that was selected for ‘University Expo 2020’ among several others,

Comment: We are not permitted to proofread your cover letter or CV. So quickly: "From **vacillating** on whether to go with this project or not."

Answer (score 1):

No, the grammar in this sentence is not correct. You have posted a sentence fragment. Also, the verb *[vacillate](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=vacillate)* is not being used correctly (note the examples).

> 1. To be unable to choose between different courses of action or opinions; waver: She vacillated about whether to leave.
> 2. To change between one state and another; fluctuate: The weather vacillated between sunny and rainy.
> 3. Archaic To sway from one side to the other.